# tuned lacks oracle profile. How could I switch to it?

Tags: oracle-12c, tuning

I'm trying to configure tuned using [this tutorial](http://houseofbrick.com/rhel-7-0-tuned-configuration/)

And following it I'm trying to switch to oracle profile:

```
# tuned-adm profile oracle
```

> Invalid profile. Use 'tuned-adm list' to get all available profiles.

```
# tuned-adm list
```

> ```
> Available profiles:
> - desktop-powersave
> - spindown-disk
> - default
> - virtual-guest
> - virtual-host
> - throughput-performance
> - enterprise-storage
> - latency-performance
> - laptop-battery-powersave
> - laptop-ac-powersave
> - server-powersave
> Current active profile: default
> ```

So how to switch to profile that does not exist in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [tuned-adm oracle's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/power_management_guide/tuned-adm), I've found the next:

> oracle   A profile optimized for Oracle databases loads based on
>   throughput-performance profile. It additionaly disables
>   transparent huge pages and modifies some other performance related
>   kernel parameters. This profile is provided by
>   tuned-profiles-oracle package. It is available in Red Hat
>   Enterprise Linux 6.8 and later.

So, the installation of the tuned-profiles-oracle package solved this issue:

```
# yum install tuned-profiles-oracle

# tuned-adm profile oracle

# tuned-adm active
```

> ```
> Current active profile: oracle
> Service tuned: enabled, running
> Service ktune: enabled, running
> ```